# spring java xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

im using spring for my java web app. the site has got bigger and i would like to set some configurations.

i have been researching and came across things like document builder factory, replacing spring xml with java config and others. i dunno where to start.

im thinking of implementing the configurations in xml (WEB/newConfig.xml) and have it read by the java beans. basically i wanna input my cofiguration values into xml and have it load by a java bean so that i can use it in controllers and jstl.

im just giving some examples here. for example xml configurations:

```
<property name="numberOfCars" value="3" />
<property name="webSiteName" value="New Spring Web App" />
....
```

and i read it in my java class:

```
class Config {

 public getNumberOfCars() {
   return numOfCars;
 } 

 public getWebSiteName() {
   return webSiteName;
 } 
}
```

where should i start and what online materials can i read?

==============================

## update

here is what i have created.

```
applicationContext.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/your_prop_file.properties" />
<bean id="ConfigMgr" class="org.domain.class.ConfigMgr">
 <property name="username" value="${username}">
</bean>

</beans>
```

you_prop_file.properties

```
username=hello world name
```

ConfigMgr.java

```
public class ConfigMgr {
 private String username;

...getter

...setter
}
```

in my controller, here is what i did:

```
ConfigMgr config = new ConfigMgr();
sysout.out.println(config.getUsername());
```

i am getting null and i am sure im missing something here. where should i set the username value to the ConfigMgr class?

Comment: read the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/)... it has more than required information

Comment: Asking for off site resources is off topic on stackoverflow. However, the place you need to start is Chapter 5 The IoC container of the Spring 3.2.4 documentation.

Comment: ok tks man.. will look into the documentation. i seems to be violating stackoverflow these days =|

Comment: is it okay to keep the configuration properties in a `properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Java configuration is a newer feature that allows you to configure your Spring application using Java classes instead of XML files. Its just an alternative for XML configuration. XML way is equally feature rich.

From what I could figure out from your problem, you  want to move the hardcoded values of params (numberOfCars,webSiteName.. )  outisde your configuration file.

If that is the case, you don't have to go that far.

Just use :-

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:your_prop_file.properties" />
```

in your spring xml file and replace the param values like:-

```
<property name="webSiteName" value="${website.name}" />
```

You need to have a your_prop_file.properties file in your classpath with enteries like:-

```
website.name=New Spring Web App
```

Comment: hi kumar tks for the reply. im alittle new here so pardon me. where should i add this <context:property-placeholder../>?? in the servlet.xml and also where should i place this properties file? in the WEB-INF or resource dir?

Comment: <context:property-placeholder/> should be added in your spring xml configuration file (applicationContext.xml for e.g.).
Place the .properties file in any source folder which is included in your classpath.

Comment: hey kumar, i have input my update. pls see above. im not sure where should i set the value of username to ConfigMgr class. am i even doing it correctly? do i even need to implement ConfigMgr.java?

Comment: Spring does not come into picture when you create a bean using 'new' operator.  You need to get bean from an ApplicationContext.  I suggest you to go through some basic Spring IOC tutorials / documents first and get your fundamental clear.

Comment: hey tks kumar, i managed to get it working. omg this has been mind boggling for me for almost 2 wks.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are not **injecting** the `ConfigMgr` bean that you created in XML file.
What you are doing is you are creating a new Object in controller which does not have a clue about properties file.
Now you can inject it using either `@Autowired` inside your controller or through xml configuration.
There are plenty of examples available in google on basic spring dependency injection.

Comment: ya man i realise i had to use auto wired.. im still trying to get use to j2ee coming from open source. haha it has been a journey.

Comment: U ll love it once u get the taste of it :) .. btw u can upvote it so that others can at least get the answer..